# php и excel - генерация web-страниц

Tags: php, excel, html

Каковы возможности существующих парсеров и библиотек для работы с excelем? Можно ли из страниц прайс-листов в экселе, с картинками и замысловатым форматированием текста генерировать похожие легкие html и какие инструменты для этого лучше использовать?

Answer (score 2):

Легкие - вряд ли. Настоящие парсеры легко извлекают данные из XLS, XLSX(без пароля), с натяжкой - форматирование. Но о генерации страниц, да еще и легких речи быть не может.
Все работают примерно одинаково медленно, что-то выдающееся посоветовать не могу. Платные не смотрел.
Из прайслистов лучше выдирать контент, а потом заново компоновать в предопределенный шаблон. Будет и быстрее и качественнее.

Answer (score 1):

не обязательно, есть замечательная OpenSourse GPL библиотека
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ PHPExсel , парсит, генерирует, любые форматы связанные с ЭКсель, именно Гнумерик,Оффис2003 2007 Эксель,ОпенКалк и другие подобные